# How to get zone wise DNS query Count on W2008R2 using Powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, dns

I have W2008R2 DNS Server, and i have `47 Zones` in my DNS Server and i would like to get Queries count Zone wise.

I can able to get the total queires using dnscmd,

```
dnscmd Servername /statistics 00000002
```

I tried installing the modules of power shell to make it work for `Get-DnsServerZone but it throws invalid name space error`, also the module not supports on Windows2008R2.

So i have tried installing the DNS server roles on remote Machine(Windows2019)  and still i am unable to get the queries count.

```
Get-DnsServer -ComputerName "servername"
```

**how to get zone wise DNS query Count either dnscmd or powershell equivalent on W2008R2.**

Comment: The Get-DNSServer powershell is not working in the W2008R2, Even i couldn't get the Zone wise Statistics report in W2008R2.